# Understanding CleanupTime in Ola Hallengren's SQL Server scripts in relation to FULL backups and LOG backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

I am having trouble understanding what exactly to expect from the `CleanupTime` option in the [Ola Hallengren Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/). I'm finding some related questions, and elaborate answers, but the explanations still puzzle me a bit.

Specifically:

I am doing a weekly FULL backup, a daily DIFF backup, and an hourly LOG backup.
The FULL backup is using the default `CleanupTime` of 24h. The DIFF and LOG backup have NULL as `CleanupTime`.

From the [documentation of the CleanupTime paramter](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html), I fail to understand if setting the `CleanupTime` setting for a backup of `BackupType` FULL, will also delete older DIFF and LOG backup files, or *only* FULL backup files.

> Specify the time, in hours, after which the backup files are deleted.
>   If no time is specified, then no backup files are deleted.

The latter paragraph makes me think that setting `CleanupTime` on backups of `BackupType` FULL will also delete older transaction logs. Yet it is unclear if this paragraph only applies to backups of the `BackupType` LOG, or also to backups of the `BackupType` FULL.

> DatabaseBackup has a check to verify that transaction log backups that
>   are newer than the most recent full or differential backup are not
>   deleted.

What I am trying to achieve, is that I can do a point-in-time recovery up to 1 week. (We have a very slowly changing database, so this is feasible) The way I understand it now, this would require a week old full backup, and a weeks worth of Transaction log backup. Since the full, and differential backups can only be used to restore to one specific point in time.

So, should I just set the `CleanupTime` option of my FULL backup job to `24*7`? What I'm guessing now is that setting it to 24h, will cause the next FULL backup to delete all older Full, diff **and** Transaction log backup files, leaving me with a point-in-time recovery window of ... 0 hours. Right?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `@CleanupTime` is always specified for a specific backup job. For example, if you create a **Full** backup job, a **Differential** backup job and a **Transaction Log** backup job, then the `@CleanupTime` always relates to the extension of the job.

Let's take a look at a **Full** backup example.

### Full Backup

If you create a full backup job, then you will normally add one or more of the following parameters:

- `@Databases` : Which databases get backed up (not really relevant for this example)
- `@Directory` : The directory to store the backups
- `@BackupType` : Full, Differential, TLog
- `@CleanupTime` : How much hours worth of backups to keep
- `@FileExtensionFull` : The extension of your backup.

So you have a backup job in place that will create a **full** backup according to the schedule you defined for the at job. Let's assume the following:

- this job runs at 20:00 (8 p.m.)
- `@FileExtensionFull` has been set to `'BAK'`
- `@Directory` has been set to `'F:\SQLBACKUP'`
- `@CleanupTime` has been set to `24` (hours)

If we look at the `MaintenanceSolution.sql` file then you will find the description for the parameter:

> ```
> SET @CleanupTime         = NULL         
> -- Time in hours, after which backup files are deleted. If no time is specified, then no backup files are deleted.
> ```

Well, that's not helping much. Same as in the official documentation on the site. Let's dig further. If you scan through the script you will eventually find a section that looks like this:

<sub>*The script has been wrapped to increase readability*</sub>

```
IF @BackupSoftware IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentCommandType02 = 'xp_delete_file'
        SET @CurrentCommand02 = 
            'DECLARE @ReturnCode int 
            EXECUTE @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.xp_delete_file 0, 
                N''' + REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryPath,'''','''''') + ''', -- first parameter
                ''' + @CurrentFileExtension + ''', --second parameter
                ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(19),@CurrentCleanupDate,126) + ''' -- third parameter
        IF @ReturnCode  0 RAISERROR(''Error deleting files.'', 16, 1)'
    END
```

So Ola is basically using the built-in `xp_delete_file function` of SQL Server to delete a file at a certain time according to:

- `@CurrentDirectoryPath`
- `@CurrentFileExtension`
- `@CurrentCleanupDate`

But wait what would for example, the `@CurrentCleanupDate` be? If we go back a bit in the script you can find a section that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO @CurrentCleanupDates (CleanupDate, Mirror)
    SELECT DATEADD(hh,-(@CleanupTime),GETDATE()), 0
```

Ah, so the `@CurrentCleanupDate` is a date addition which is calculated from the `@CleanupTime` and the current time `GETDATE()`. Cool.
<sub>*(...and we might have just found a typo in the code, because the sections for normal and mirror database both contain **`Mirror`** in the code.)*</sub>

What is the relevant section then for `@CurrentFileExtension`? Let's search around a bit again. And we find:

```
SELECT @CurrentFileExtension = CASE
    WHEN @CurrentBackupType = 'FULL' THEN @FileExtensionFull
    WHEN @CurrentBackupType = 'DIFF' THEN @FileExtensionDiff
    WHEN @CurrentBackupType = 'LOG' THEN @FileExtensionLog
    END
```

So there you have it.

### Summary

If the parameters for your **Full** backup job are set as `@FileExtensionFull='BAK'` and you have set a `@CleanupTime=24` then the procedure will delete all **Full** backup files that are at least a day old (24 hours).

The `@CurrentCommand02` that gets executed is basically:

```
xp_delete_file 0, 'F:\SQLBACKUP', 'BAK', '2018-08-20 20:00:00.045'
```

So it doesn't touch on any other backup files. (Unless of course you have defined `'BAK'` to be the extension of all backup types, in which case you lose).

Comment: With the current version there is no issue generated by having non-custom file extensions for DIFF, LOG and normal backups. What I wanted to mention though, was that `@CleanupTime` works for the currently executing type of backup. So if you're performing daily FULL backups with 24h cleanup time, it will essentially delete ALL full backups older than 24h. Then if you also do DIFF backups with a 24h cleanup time, and for example if you perform these backups every 2 hours, you will end up with DIFF backups that have NO corresponding FULL backup, because some diffs are not yet older than 24 hours.

Comment: *Continued* - So a fix to the above situation I pointed out, would be to add additional time to the FULL backup's cleanup time, equal to the amount of time in hours between the last DIFF backup's time and the next FULL backup's time. So that would be 29 hours. For safety, I would also add one extra hour. I currently use 30 hours for FULL backups and 24 hours for DIFF backups that run every 2 hours between 10 and 22 (10 PM). I don't do TLog backups in this example.

Comment: *Continued* -  You could plot the backups by type, as time spans on a common time axis, with length = their cleanup times (ie. lifetimes!). If a set (FULL + its DIFFs or at least the LAST DIFF! + its TLogs or ALL TLogs after the LAST DIFF) overlaps vertically, then you have correct cleanup times for all of them. If not, you may end up with missing dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

I upvoted @hot2use's answer as it covers this question in detail, but I did want to share an easy way to test this stuff.

It might help you (as it helped me) to fully understand how the script works if you:

1. Install the backup script (and other dependencies) on a test instance - I tested on my local computer.
2. Now, alter the script and search/replace `hh` with `minute`.  The only references I can find with `hh` are where the script is dealing with the cleanup time.  This allows you to quickly run backups of various types (FULL, DIFF, LOG) see the effects of the execution because the retention is in minutes and not hours.

Run a FULL, DIFF and LOG backup of a test database and note the files created in the individual folders.  This is what I used (note the `CleanupTime` of 1 minute due to alter the script from hours to minutes):

```
exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'test',
@Directory = 'C:\OlaBackupTest',
@BackupType = 'full',
@Verify = 'N',
@CleanupTime = 1,
@CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP'

exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'test',
@Directory = 'C:\OlaBackupTest',
@BackupType = 'diff',
@Verify = 'N',
@CleanupTime = 1,
@CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP'

exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'test',
@Directory = 'C:\OlaBackupTest',
@BackupType = 'log',
@Verify = 'N',
@CleanupTime = 1,
@CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP'
```

---

My testing revealed the following observations:

**FULL**

Every execution of a `FULL` backup created a new `FULL` backup and deleted any `FULL` backup files older than 1 minute.  No `DIFF` or `LOG` backup files were ever affected.

**DIFF**

Every execution of a `DIFF` backup created a new `DIFF` backup and deleted any `DIFF` backup files older than 1 minute.  No `FULL` or `LOG` backup files were ever affected.

**LOG**

Every execution of a `LOG` backup created a new `LOG` backup.  Continuous `LOG` backups (without intervening `FULL` or `DIFF` backups) simply continued to accumulate in the `LOG` backup folder without regard to the cleanup time.  If a `FULL` or `DIFF` backup was eventually taken, the NEXT run of the `LOG` backup deleted any `LOG` backups older than the latest `FULL` or `DIFF` and also older than 1 minute.

No `FULL` or `DIFF` backup files were ever affected while running `LOG` backups.

---

I would recommend keeping more than 1 week of `FULL` backups in the event you need to go back in time to restore.  Assuming 2 weeks of `FULL` backups, you'd need a `CleanupTime` of 336 hours.

During your testing of the 1 minute stuff, you'll see that:

- Running `FULL` backups never delete `DIFF` or `LOG` backups
- Running `DIFF` backups never delete `FULL` or `LOG` backups
- Running `LOG` backups never delete `FULL` or `DIFF` backups

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other two answers, because I just encountered this:

May be worth noting (to whomever may google this). to allow for a little bit more than the exact time you want to keep your backup.

If op wants to keep the 1-week old backup, the 24x7 hours won´t always keep the 1-week old file. Reason: Databases are growing. You new backup might take slightly Longer.

If your first backup file was create
  2020-03-15 03:00:05.000
And the next backup takes a bit longer and file is created
2020-03-22 30:00:0**6**.000 - that´s more than the specified 168 hours (one second, mind you)

**So to be safe, make it 24x7+1!**